# Issues with executing JavaScript functions from HTML rendered by XSLT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xslt

I'm still relatively new to XSLT and I have a problem I hope someone can help with.  I'm rendering an HTML page using XSLT.  I found out how to include an external .js file in the XSL file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"><xsl:comment>X</xsl:comment></script>
```

This properly rendered the script tag in the HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"><!-- comment --></script>
```

However none of the functions in the JavaScript file are accessible.  The jQuery $(document).ready event isn't being executed either when the HTML is rendered.  How can I get the rendered HTML to actually execute the JavaScript?

Any ideas?

If I should provide any additional information please let me know.

Comment: Just to be sure  - some version of jquery.js is also included in the HTML?

Comment: Just so you know, this has nothing to do with XSLT. If the HTML is being rendered as expected, then XSLT has been and gone. Not sure why you've got a comment inside the script tag; when loading an external script, the tag should be empty.

Comment: I agree with Utkanos, XSLT is upstream of your problem. Important: XSLT does not know Javascript - `text/javascript` is just another attribute that is correctly serialized to HTML.

Comment: usually you have to load jQuery.js before a common scripts file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I'll go sit in the corner with the kids that eat paste now!!

Yes the issue was that I didn't have the jQuery API loaded.

As for the question asked about why I had a comment inside the script tag.  Apparently when you have the XSL namespace defined as XHTML it doesn't like empty script tags.  It forces you to actually put something inside the tag.  Once I removed the XHTML definition that problem went away too.